# Import Error: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: file too short

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install matplotlib for Python 3 on my Raspberry Pi. Here's the error I get when I try to import the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/GPIOtests/Accel.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 28, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: file too short
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps [error while loading shared libraries, file too short](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24266/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-file-too-short) can help.

Comment: How do you have `python3.2` on the Pi?

Comment: I have python 3 and python 2 on my pi by default

Comment: fixed this by accident but don't know why... Maybe it just needed an restart

Comment: That is 4 years old,  it would be no harm to update it

Comment: what is 4 years old? Python 3.2?